# Installing F# PowerPack on OS X

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have F# 2.0 installed on Mono 2.6.7 on an OS X 10.6 machine.

How can I install the PowerPack and use it in FS interactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, on Windows, I downloaded the source code and compiled it into assemblies, which I referenced. I imagine it's much the same on MAC/Mono. You can reference an assembly in FSI with...

```
#r "assemblyname"
```

Comment: Also, if you don't want to compile PowerPack from sources, there is also a ZIP download that should work on Mac: http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/releases/view/45593

Comment: Thanks. I found a zip of the assemblies rather than the msi. And I needed to add the include path for FSI first.